# Response to Herbert

Tags: discussion

I don't know if you read meta or not, but you left the comment

> …interesting by the way, that you only down voted *my* answer

(emphasis yours) and then deleted your answer while I was responding.

I voted only your answer down because it was the only one that was incorrect that I could see. I don't know why that is interesting.

As I've mentioned before on meta, I don't normally vote down answers to questions I answer, but when I voted on your answer and left the comment explaining why, I had no intention of answering the question myself. A few minutes later, I remembered `\@outputpage` and thought it was worth mentioning.

I truly hope you don't think I'm going around down voting your answers because we've disagreed in the past. You frequently give very good answers (as is obvious by your meteoric rise through the user list) and, from my perspective, are a definite benefit to the site as a whole.

To everyone else: I apologize for the noise. I don't know another simple way to respond and maintain my anonymity. Hopefully, this doesn't count as "too often" for [Andrew](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/comment-overflow-lockstep-and-i-argue-about-biblatex).

Comment: I think twice in six months (?) is infrequent enough.  Definitely agree with the sentiment expressed in the last sentence of the penultimate paragraph.  I've never seen Herbert here on meta so maybe it's worth putting a comment on one of his answers directing him here.

Comment: @Andrew: Oops, there was supposed to be a smilie after that. Good point about not seeing him on meta though.

Comment: @Andrew: he was here at least once: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/920/new-tag-verb-in-difference-to-verbatim (after I sent him here when disagreeing with and edit).